# Query selector to select Button A only if site does not have Button B

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I'm creating a Chrome Browser Extension that clicks some buttons automatically whenever they appear. I'm using [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) for the watching, which uses a query Selector to watch for the html elements to click on.

```
var buttonA = 'a[data-test="begin-session-button"]'
var buttonB = 'a[data-test="skill-header-practice-button"]'

document.arrive(buttonA, function () {
  document.querySelector(buttonA).click();
});

document.arrive(buttonB, function () {
  document.querySelector(buttonB).click();
});
```

The Problem I have is some sites have both buttons `buttonA` and `buttonB`. As of now both buttons would be clicked and it is a matter of luck which one gets clicked last.

Whenever there is a site with `buttonA` and `buttonB`, only click `buttonA`. So I'm looking to alter the query for `buttonB` like:

```
document.arrive(buttonB + ' :not:' + buttonA, function () {
  document.querySelector(buttonB).click();
});
```

As a query in the Chrome Browser Console this would look like:

```
document.querySelector(
   'a[data-test="skill-header-practice-button] ' + 
   ':not:a[data-test="begin-session-button"]'
)
```

This is bad syntax and not working in the chrome brower console. How would the Correct Syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not do something like this

```
document.arrive(buttonA, function () {
  document.querySelector(buttonA).click();
});

document.arrive(buttonB, function () {
  if(document.querySelector(buttonA) == null){
    document.querySelector(buttonB).click();
  }
});
```

I can't say that I have used the arrive library before though so I could be completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is simpler to do it "programatically" than with complex selectors, something like (works with your code because `buttonA` is global, be careful that this var must be accessible to the function):

```
var buttonA = 'a[data-test="begin-session-button"]'
var buttonB = 'a[data-test="skill-header-practice-button"]'

document.arrive(buttonA, function () {
  document.querySelector(buttonA).click();
});

document.arrive(buttonB, function () {
  var buttA = document.querySelector(buttonA);
  if(buttA === null){
    document.querySelector(buttonB).click();
  }
});
```